# Array/Collection of Objects

Tags: c#, arrays, collections

I would like to create an array/collection that contains objects.  I would like to be able to access the objects in the array/collection with a key value.  I'm thinking the syntax to access the objects would be something like this:

```
ObjectArray[52].Color = "Blue"
ObjectArray[52].Height = 12.2

If(ObjectArray[52].Color == "Blue")
{
   // Code for Blue
}
If(ObjectArray[52].Height < 13.0)
{
   // Code for height less than 13.
}

class ObjectInArray
{
   public string Color;
   public double Height;
}
```

"52" in this case is a key value, not a position in the array.  Color and Blue are properties in the objects.  I do not know how to create an array/collection to do this (if it can be done).  Any help or optional suggestion how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: You are describing a `Dictionary<int, ObjectInArray>`.

Comment: Can you give an example of how your "collection" looks like? (Your explanation is quite confusing to me.)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried?

Comment: This is called a [Map or Associative Array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) and is represented by the [`IDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx) interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want an array, you want something which can associate keys of one type with values of another type. Such collection in .Net is called [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx), specifically for your case `Dictionary<int, ObjectInArray>`.

Example:

```
Dictionary<int, ObjectInArray> ObjectArray = new Dictionary<int, ObjectInArray>();
ObjectArray[52] = new ObjectInArray();

ObjectArray[52].Color = "Blue"
ObjectArray[52].Height = 12.2

if (ObjectArray[52].Color == "Blue")
{
   // Code for Blue
}

if (ObjectArray[52].Height < 13.0)
{
   // Code for height less than 13.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think Dictionary is what you are looking for

```
Dictionary<int, ObjectInArray > dict= new Dictionary<int, ObjectInArray >();
```

Comment: Only `object` should be `ObjectInArray`

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary you can store key-value pairs and then access the value based on a key.

In your example the dictionary would be `Dictionary<int, ObjectInArray>`

Answer (score 1):

`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is what you're looking for.

It is a generic collection containing values which can be accessed (through an indexer) by giving the key.

It's initialization is as follows:

```
Dictionary<int, ObjectInArray> ObjectArray = new Dictionary<int, ObjectInArray>()
{
    { /*key:*/ 52, /*value:*/ new ObjectInArray() },
    { 53, new ObjectInArray() } // Etc
};
```

And then you can use it exactly as you've written the code yourself.

The dictionary is also quite clever in that it will automatically detect whether the index you're accessing exists or not, and will create it if necessary:

```
ObjectArray[10] /* <-- Doesn't exist, will be created */ = new ObjectInArray();
```